# Scores per year in array

Tags: php, arrays

Pretty new to PHP and i'm trying to achieve something, that in my opinion can be done easily in c#. However in PHP it isn't that easy to achieve for me.

When iterating over an XML file, I want to store all average scores per year.
The years will be unique, the scores should be their values.

Output should be like:

> ['2012'] => array(8.1, 7.3, 8.8)
>   ['2013'] => array(6.7, 7.7, 5.5)
>   ['2014'] => array(2.3, 7.9, 9.9)

This way I can get all average scores from the year 2014, etc.
In c# I would have created a Dictionary containing a List like:

```
var yearScores = new Dictionary<string, List<Decimal>>();
```

My current PHP code looks like:

```
$yearScores = array(array());
foreach($xml->results->children() as $result) {
        //Reset variables
        $current_date = null;
        $current_average = null;

        //Iterate over all 'answer' children in result
        foreach($result->children() as $answer) {
            //Retrieve Date and Average
            if($average[0]['name'] == "date") {
                $current_date = date('Y', strtotime($answer));
            }
            if($average[0]['name'] == "average") {
                $current_average = $answer;
            }
        }

        //Validate if we found both current Date and current Average
        if(is_null($current_date) || is_null($current_average)) continue;

        //The Date and Average exist
        //See if the Datum already exists in our array
        if(!in_array($current_date, $yearScores)) {
            $yearScores[] = $current_date;
        }
        //The average should be added to the correct year in the array here.
}
```

How can I add the scores to the correct year arrays in the $yearScores array?

Comment: Can you shoe result of `$xml->results->children()` by printing it out?

Comment: I simplified the code earlier, now added the full code for a better understanding I hope. Will add the XML feed.

Comment: what i tell write `echo "<pre/>";print_r($xml->results->children());die; in your code before foreach`  and show that array to us by putting it in your code. simple and will more helpful.thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
// no need to initialize multidimensional array here
$yearScores = array();

foreach($xml->results->children() as $result) {

    foreach($result->children() as $answer) {
        //Retrieve Date and Average
        // This here does not look right to me
        if($average[0]['name'] == "date") {
            $current_date = date('Y', strtotime($answer));
        }
        if($average[0]['name'] == "average") {
            $current_average = $answer;
        }

        if(!isset($yearScores[$current_date])) {
            $yearScores[$current_date] = array($current_average);
        } else {
            array_push($yearScores[$current_date], $current_average);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the `if`s however (check my comment). Have you checked if their output is correct?

Comment: Where did you get the `$year` variable from? It should be `$current_date`?

Comment: It is `$current_date`; it was `$year` before you changed the code.

Comment: It should be "current_date" not "year" in the example.

Comment: @user3584460 I have one addition to your code, the $current_average is now a simpleXMLElement. Casting it to a string gave me the exact value I wanted. So: `$yearScores[$current_date] = array($current_average);` would become: `$yearScores[$current_date] = array((string)$current_average);` And `array_push($yearScores[$current_date], $current_average);` would become: `array_push($yearScores[$current_date], (string)$current_average);`

Comment: @Max Since it is a SimpleXMLElement, you can do `$current_average->__toString();` and `$current_average->__toString();` instead of casting it to string (I didn't even know that is possible :)).